# Create Database Programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, database-create

I am trying to create a database programmatically in C#. I have scripts for database creation which work fine when I run them from SQL Server Management Studio. However, when I run the same scripts from my C# application, the following error occurs:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know there is a c# frame work which will do all this for you. 
http://www.sharparchitecture.net/ it will build your DB and your data access layer from a OO model.

Answer (score 0):

public string  CreateDataBase(string ipAddress, string UserName, string Password,string DB_filepath)
        {

```
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server addDBserver = new     Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(ipAddress);
        addDBserver.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
        addDBserver.ConnectionContext.Login = UserName;
        addDBserver.ConnectionContext.Password = Password;



        try
        {
            //*Crerate Databse*
            addDBserver.ConnectionContext.Connect();
            FileInfo filedb = new FileInfo(DB_filepath);
            string scriptdb = filedb.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            string scriptdb1 = scriptdb.Replace("GO", Environment.NewLine);
            string scriptdb2 = scriptdb1.Replace("\r\nGO\r\n", "");
            addDBserver.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(scriptdb2);
            addDBserver.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
            string Msg;
                Msg = "db created successfully";
                return Msg;
            return true;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
       string Msg1 = "db notcreated successfully";
         return ex.Message;
           throw;
        }
    }
        //Database created Successfully
```